# Reed switch stays ON

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic

I have an anemometer reed switch connected to a uC with a 10K pull-up. I then have a RC filter to debounce around 500Hz. This is the case:

[image: schematic]

A fairly old anemometer connected to my board powers the reed switch @3V3. I cant seem to get a "low" seen on the uC pin. It seems to stay ON at about 2V5 when magnetised.
Now there is another board that powers the reed switch @5V. The system can see a "low" on its input. I believe this has to do with the DC characteristics of the uC and registers 2V5 as a "low" wheres on a 3V3 this isnt true.
If I get a new anemometer then my system can actually see a "low" and count pulses.

Does this have to do with the aging of the reed switch? The 5V system might see a pulse but for how long?

Comment: Can you add a schematic? We have an awesome on-site schematic editor, which you can start-up with Ctrl-M.

Comment: As above a schematic would help. Another step worth doing would be to measure the resistance of the new / old device by rotating it manually until the contacts are closed.

Comment: Reed switch? If you can hear it clicking it's still switching and capable of giving good logic levels. Problems are more likely in your filter topology (hence we need to see the schematic) or corrosion on any outdoor connectors. The trouble with weather stations is ... weather.

Comment: I dont have access to the anemometer and unfortunately I cant do tests. It is located at a partners work 3 hours away from me and we are doing testing. Yes, corrosion is an issue the anemometers do have a life expectancy and when they read 0 they get replaced. Ok I will add schematic.

Comment: Here is the schematic. http://i.stack.imgur.com/crcOm.png

Comment: When I mean old, I mean its been out exposed to weather for around 8 years.

Comment: If you increase R1's value, you still get 2.5V?. Brian is right, if it is a reed switch, it should switch on pretty good. Measuring that contact resistance should give you a clue, try with 10K, 1K, and 20K for R1 and measure the output voltage in each case. The results should tell you what's going on.

Comment: First low pass filtering is not the same as debouncing.  However, the real question is what is the voltage right on the switch, or at the left end of R2?  is that going up and down as intended?  If not, then something is broken, possible a wire or the reed switch.

Comment: Given this schematic I have to ask if the CPU pin has an internal pullup : if so, is there a programming option to disable the pullup? Assuming you measure good levels at the switch as Olin suggested.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It seems you found it. The user already wrote an answer, but you might want to think about it also if you would like to write something more detailed about this.

Answer (score 2):

After Brians suggestion I changed the input pin pull-up to a Tristate and it solved the problem! 
Apparently the problem appeared when I changed from input pins to a timer capture pin and it was setting the pull-up as default.

Thank you for pointing it out.